# problem in displaying a xib as Ipad in universal application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, universal-binary

I have an already running iphone app with target OS 3.1. I am trying to transform it into a universal app.
I am not going to change the model, only the xib.
So I wrote the ipad xib in IB, then I went to info.plist and add MainIpad Nib for ipad pointing to a proper MainIpad.xib.
I also set Target Device Family in project info to ipad/iphone.

That seems to be not enough, whenever I run ipad simulator, I always get the MainIpad.xib view resized as iphone, actually it's just showing an iphone inside an ipad. I also tried to set the CGRect manually to the ipad size. The result is a bigger view still clipped into an iphone.

Can you point out what I am doing wrong and suggest the proper way to convert in universal app ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you point out what I am doing
>   wrong and suggest the proper way to
>   convert in universal app ?

The proper way? That's easy. From page 20 of the iPad Programming Guide:

> **Important:** You should always use the
>   Upgrade Current Target for iPad
>   command to migrate existing projects.
>   Do not try to migrate files manually.

By your problem description, it looks like you tried to migrate the files manually.

My advice to you is: start over using a copy of your project before you started the migration. (You *did* save a copy of the project before you started the conversion, like a good programmer should do, right?)

Comment: Yes, the project was on svn, so no problem in that sense. But rather than going back to versioning, it has been enough to go to in project info-->architectures, and delete all unecessary entries. Then convert target again. And the problem disappeared...but the original advice was right :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    if(!settingsController)
        settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ipadSettingsController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsController animated:YES]; 
    [settingsController release];
}else {
    if(!settingsController)
    settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsController animated:YES]; 
    [settingsController release];
}
```

Comment: I don't think User Interface Idiom works in os 3.1, I will check but I can sort it out in a different way. But I don't understand, where do I need to put such code ? You are telling me that I need to write a new controller for every new ipad xib created ? And what new code should I put in there, in addition to existing one ?

Comment: sorry, misunderstood. It's not a new controller, but a new view, I am already doing it. The problem lies somewhere else, the ipad view get properly find and loaded, but it always get clipped into iphone view.

Comment: use the another xib which is targeted for ipad.

Answer (score 1):

grt tutoial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Answer (score 0):

use the another xib which is targeted for ipad.